# Why is acetylsalicylic acid still more acid than benzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, drugs, medicinal-chemistry

In [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20190/why-does-hydrogen-bonding-in-salicylic-acid-make-it-more-acidic) question, it is explained why salicylic acid is a stronger acid than benzoic acid. So, why acetylsalicylic acid (aspirin), whose conjugate base cannot hydrogen bond since there is no hydrogen, is still more acid than benzoic acid?

- aspirin: $\mathrm{p}K_\text{a}$ = 3.5
- benzoic acid: $\mathrm{p}K_\text{a}$ = 4.2

Acetoxyl is a moderate activating group for the aromatic electrophilic substitution, so it should mean that the resonance-driven electron-donating effect prevails over the inductive electron-withdrawing effect, therefore it should raise the $\mathrm{p}K_\text{a}$ of the acid.

Is it different between electrophilic substitution reactivity and acidity? Does the inductive effect prevail in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acetyl moiety in acetylsalicylic acid has a $(-I)$-effect, i.e. compared to a proton attached to the aromatic ring (as in the case of benzoic acid), it withdraws electron density out of the aromatic ring.  This provides an *additional* stabilization of the conjugated base, that is equivalent with rendering acetylsalicylic acid a stronger Brønsted acid than benzoic acid.  Hence, the $pK_a$ of acetylsalicylic acid is lower than the one of benzoic acid.

Regarding the second paragraph, please notice $pK_a$ is a thermodynamic property -- where time does not play a role.  In contrast, the substitution reactivity you likely refer to ([Hammett parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_equation)) refers to reaction kinetics and rate constants.  Here, time does play a role.