# Why is salicylic acid less acidic than o- anisic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, stability

The [Pka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salicylic_acid) of salicylic acid is 2.97 while that of o-anisic acid is [3.73](https://hmdb.ca/metabolites/HMDB0032604).
Why is the latter less acidic if the order of [+M effect](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Purdue/Purdue%3A_Chem_26200%3A_Organic_Chemistry_II_(Wenthold)/Chapter_15._Reactions_of_Aromatic_Molecules/15.03%3A_Substitution_effects_on_orientation/15.03.1%3A_Theory_of_Directing_effects) states that -OH>-OR which should make the conjugate base less stable?

Comment: You might have messed up the data and thus in turn the entire post. $\mathrm{pK_a}$ of salicylic acid is 2.79 and that of o-anisic acid is 3.73.

Comment: @Rishi i corrected it

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20190/why-does-hydrogen-bonding-in-salicylic-acid-make-it-more-acidic